# Can't run python file without .py extension even after adding shebang

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7, shebang

Couldn't get my python script to execute without .py extension even after adding `#!/usr/bin/python3` to the script but the shebang works because i could execute the script without python keyword but i also need the .py extension out, i need the it to work like a cli keyword like git,is there a way to accomplish this on windows without adding the path to environment variables?

Comment: This may be an issue with the assumptions Windows makes about extensions. It enforces file extension / file type relationships pretty strictly.

Comment: Please clarify what you've tried. "Couldn't get my python script to execute without .py extension even after adding #!/usr/bin/python3 to the script but the shebang works" doesn't make much sense. Either it works or it doesn't.

Comment: considering that `git` adds itself to the `PATH` environment variable, it's not really possible to make your file a cli keyword without modifying your `PATH` unless you are in the same folder where the file is, so you cannot get an answer unless you losen that constraint.

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3` is a Linux filepath, and is usually where the python binary is stored on Linux filesystems; it doesn't make much sense to put it in a Windows python file.

Comment: @MichaelRuth what i meant by that is that the shebang works when i don't add the python keyword normally i have to type ```python hello.py``` for the script to execute but with the shebang ```hello.py``` works but ```hello``` doesn't  work but i need ```hello``` to work like a cli tool keyword

Comment: @bobtho'-' well ```/usr/bin/python3``` actually works on my windows pc, i tried ```/usr/bin/env  python3``` at first but didn't work

Comment: Are you using [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)?

Comment: yea i installed wsl some time ago when i needed to install docker on my pc